# phonegap upload image on form type file

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, ajaxform

I am trying to use ajax.form.js to upload image since form is not compatible with the filetransfer of phonegap.

The javascript

```
            $('#sign-up-form').ajaxForm({ 
                //target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 

                success: function(data) { 
                    //alert(data);
                    alert('ok');

                } 
            });
```

The php

```
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/profile/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '5024';
    $config['max_width']  = '5024';
    $config['max_height']  = '5024';
    $config['file_name']  = $username;
```

It uploads on html local browser but gives this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tried it on phonegap but it doesn't work but it goes to success checked server no image is uploaded.

Advise on how to do this is very much appreciated and please tell me if I should use another method which will be much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* to the header?

Older versions of Phonegap have a blocklist of URLs as well. Try adding your server to the allowed domains.

You can find a guide to add your domain to the whitelist here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: well I still have the    <access origin=".*"/> default so I doubt that is the problem. Also text data is easy used ajax and it works the problem is the file type input

Comment: Ok then, I think I missed that part with the image. :)
You cannot user XmlHTTPRequest to post files via ajax, because (as far as I know) it does not have acces to the file system.

You can either try:

- Not using ajax

- Using a hidden iFrame for forms data.